# How to Bind JDK in Tomcat using PowerShell Script without setting environment variables

Tags: java, powershell, sql-server-2014

Actually requirement is, PowerShell Script installs the Tomcat Service and Bind with JDK without any set environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

This may not meet your requirement, but for Tomcat installed from a `.zip` distribution. Create a `setenv.bat` (for windows) under `CATALINA_BASE\bin` directory (`CATALINA_BASE` is the Tomcat installation directory) and put this into the file:

```
set "JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre"
exit /b 0
```

This file does not exist by default, the Tomcat’s start up script (startup.bat/startup.sh) will invoke the `setenv.bat` script if it is present. This way will not affect the system environment variables.
You can refer to [this link](http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/4-ways-to-change-jre-for-tomcat) to find if there is a way suitable for you.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for the answer, but Can u plz tell me this JRE_HOME is set in Windows environment or not? Actually, My requirement is Start Tomcat without setting a windows environment variable.

Comment: This will set environment variables for tomcat, it is temporary and don't affect other applications.